# умственноотсталого / умственно отсталого увидел

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Я в школе одного умственноотсталого / умственно отсталого увидел.`

Comment: Я в школе одного умственно отсталого видел./В школе я увидел одного умственно отсталого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое словосочетание пишется раздельно:

***Я в школе одного умственно отсталого увидел***.

Слова *умственноотсталый* нет и быть не может. Писать слитно — грубая ошибка.

---

Здесь идет сочетание прилагательного *отсталого* с наречием образа действия — *умственно*. А по правилам, если от прилагательного к наречию можно задать вопрос, то они между собой пишутся **раздельно**:

*Отсталый (как?) умственно*.

То есть вопрос подразумевает, **в чем он отсталый**. В данном случае в уме, и задается вопрос *как?*

---

Вывод: корректно раздельное написание: ***умственно отсталый***.

---

Читайте подробнее в [справочнике Розенталя, пункт 17](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49).

Answer (score 3):

[умственно отсталый](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

*Я в школе одного умственно отсталого увидел.*